# Crossrider ajax post requests having JSON payload are not received correctly in Rails backend

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, crossrider

I have a JSON object that I want to post to a remote server (Rails). All attempts to send it to the server as 'application/json' fail where POST parameters are converted somewhere to url-encoded string.
For example:

```
appAPI.request.post({
  url: "http://mybackend",
  postData: {hello: 'world', foo: 'bar'},
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    console.log("postback succeeded with response: " + response)
  },
  onFailure: function(httpCode) {
    console.log("postback failure: " + httpCode)
  },
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Returns HTTP 500 with the server complaining from a malformed JSON object:

```
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

MultiJson::LoadError (784: unexpected token at 'hello=world&foo=bar'): 
  /Users/hammady/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
  ...
```

What else should I do to send the JSON object to my Rails backend?

Comment: read this link. LMK if anything is unclear https://coderwall.com/p/c-mu-a

Comment: Try to stringify the object first.
postData: JSON.stringify({hello: 'world', foo: 'bar'})

Comment: @Bnaya this solved my problem, please add it as a solution!

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361568/711152

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stringify the object first.

```
postData: JSON.stringify({hello: 'world', foo: 'bar'});
```

Answer (score 1):

use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to stringify the posted data

```
appAPI.request.post({
  url: "http://mybackend",
  postData: JSON.stringify({hello: 'world', foo: 'bar'}),
  onSuccess: function(response) {
    console.log("postback succeeded with response: " + response)
  },
  onFailure: function(httpCode) {
    console.log("postback failure: " + httpCode)
  },
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
```